# True or False Statement [Set Theory]

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[Statement Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8w0X.png)

Hi, I just need help with this true or false statement.

> $A\setminus(B\cup C)=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\setminus C)$ for all sets $A$, $B$, and $C$.

I think its true because $A\cup A=A$ and in the denominator $B\cup C=B\cup C$.. Just need more feedback on this. Thank you!

Comment: I’m afraid that your reasoning strongly suggests that you don’t understand the set operations involved. There are no fractions here, so there are no denominators. $A\setminus(B\cup C)$ is by definition the set of things that are elements of the set $A$ but **not** elements of the set $B\cup C$. Are you familiar with Venn diagrams? If so, try drawing the Venn diagram of this set.

Comment: "I think its true because A∪A=A and in the denominator B∪C=B∪C"  I .... don't understand what you mean, and if I did, I don't understand what that has to do with the question.

Comment: Note that if $w \in X\setminus Y$, then $w \in X \land w\notin Y$.  Alternatively, $X\setminus Y =  X \cap Y^c$, where $Y^c$ is the complement of $Y$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Although to slight degree and with great care not to take it *literally*, set operations can be analogous to arithmetic.  With $\cup$ being analogous to $+$ and $\cap$ being analogous  to $\times$.  But if so "setminus" $\setminus$ is analogous to subtraction and *NOT* division.  I can't really think of anything being analogous to division.  (Except maybe partitions and equivalence classes?  In any event so analogies are *LOOSE* analogies and must be taking with a grain of salt).  In any event I don't see why you think splitting the "denominator" applies.  I don't get your argument.

Comment: So....?  Are you arguing that $(A\setminus C)\cup (B\setminus D)=(A\cup B)\setminus (C\cup D) $?  As though these were fractions?  I'm afraid that's not in the least bit true and is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $j \in A; j\in B; j\not \in C$.  Suppose $k \in A;k\not \in B; k \in C$.

Suppose $m \in A; m\in B; m\in C$.  Suppose $n\in A; n\not \in B; n\not \in C$.

Which of those elements are in:

$A$?, $B$?, $C$?, $B\cup C$?, $A\setminus B$?, $A\setminus C$?, $A\setminus (B\cup C)$?, $(A\setminus B)\cup (A\setminus C)$?